# add a record to has_many model without saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A customer has many orders.
So customer.orders gives me all orders.

I want to add an order to his orders but for an internal check.
I don't want this order to be actually added to the data base.

But when doing:

```
customer.orders << test_order
```

It is being saved and committed to the data base.

So how can I add it for my use without saving?

Comment: try to write like this: `Order.new(test_order).where(:customer_id => customer.id)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use build, which will just initialize the order object without saving it.

```
test_order = customer.orders.build(order_params)
```

Comment: Will that line give me all the orders including the test order?

Comment: `customer.orders` if used after building it.